# How can I add CustomerId parameter to the basic authentication form in Swagger UI using Asp.net 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I am creating a WebAPI project using ASP.net 5 with Swagger UI.

I have added basic authentication scheme to authenticate the user using a username and password. However, I also need to send a `CustomerId` parameter in the header in addition to the username and password.

How can I configure SwaggerUI to add a field called `CustomerId` to the authentication form so that The form required `Username`, `Password` and `CustomerId`?

This is how I am configuring the basic authentication

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{  

    services.AddControllers();  

    #region Configure Swagger  
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>  
    {  
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "BasicAuth", Version = "v1" });  
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("basic", new OpenApiSecurityScheme  
        {  
            Name = "Authorization",  
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,  
            Scheme = "basic",  
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,  
            Description = "Basic Authorization header using the Bearer scheme."  
        });  
        c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement  
        {  
            {  
                  new OpenApiSecurityScheme  
                    {  
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference  
                        {  
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,  
                            Id = "basic"  
                        }  
                    },  
                    new string[] {}  
            }  
        });  
    });
}
```

Comment: "The "Basic" HTTP authentication scheme is defined in RFC 7617, which transmits credentials as user ID/password pairs, encoded using base64." from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#basic_authentication_scheme.

Comment: You should NOT be mixing authentication modes here. If you want to provide a customer id as well as basic auth credentials, you should pass it to the api as part of the contract or as a custom header or, better yet, replace both with an encrypted bearer token.

Comment: OpenAPI YAML/JSON does support [combining multiple security schemes](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/#multiple), such as Basic auth + an extra HTTP header; or 2+ API keys, or similar. You would need to define the `CustomerId` header as an API key security scheme, and add it as an additional security requirement. The JSON generated by Swashbuckle needs have this: `"security": [ {"basic": []}, {"CustomerId": []} ]`. Then when you click the "Authorize" button in Swagger UI, you would have fields for Basic auth username and password AND CustomerId.